# Checking the convexity of a quadratic function with bilinear terms

Tags: polynomials, convex-analysis, quadratic-forms

I have a function of the following form

$$a(b(x^2 +y^2+z^2 +xy + xz + yz)+ x+y+z)$$

where $a, b > 0$. Is this function convex? How can we show convexity? Thank you.

Comment: What would the second derivative be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $(x,y,z) \mapsto x+y+z$ is linear hence convex.

The Hessian of $(x,y,z) \mapsto x^2+y^2+z^2+xy+yz+xz$ is
$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ which is symmetric, real and 
has eigenvalues $1,1,4$.

If $f$ is convex and $b > 0$ then $b \cdot f$  is convex.

If $g,h$ are convex and $a >0$ then $a(g+h)$ is convex.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Comment: Just thought I'd point out that the convexity of $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + xy + yz + xz$ is also apparent by re-expressing it as $\frac{1}{2}\left( (x+y)^2 + (y+z)^2 + (z+x)^2 \right)$.

Comment: @madnessweasley: That would be a much better way!